# 1000 Digit Fibonacci - Error on Euler?

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

Below is my code. It runs. It works.
The problem is, the INDEX of the first 1000 digit fibonacci number isn't 4872...it's 4871.  4872 is the POSITION, not the INDEX.  Is Euler accepting the wrong answer, or did they use the word index when they should have used position?

```
def fib_of_a_certain_digit(num)
    fibs = [1, 1]
    idx = 1
    while true 
      fib = fibs[idx] + fibs[idx-1]
      fibs << fib
      idx += 1
      digilength = fib.to_s.split("").length
      return "The first #{num} digit Fibonacci number is at index #{idx}, the fibonacci array is #{fibs.length} long" if digilength == num
     end
end

puts fib_of_a_certain_digit(3)
puts fib_of_a_certain_digit(1000)
```

Here is the output.
The first 3 digit Fibonacci number is at index 11, the fibonacci array is 12 long
The first 1000 digit Fibonacci number is at index 4781, the fibonacci array is 4782 long

As you can see, the control case matches the known data.
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
The last number in the array is 144.  It is at index 11, but is the 12th number in the array.
The same principle applies to the larger number (it's just too big to paste here).  It winds up in the last position of the array (4872), which has the index of 4871.

Why has nobody else noticed this?

Comment: maybe they started with 0 and 1

Comment: In this case they started with [1, 1]. https://projecteuler.net/problem=25
"Hence the first 12 terms will be:
F1 = 1
F2 = 1
et cetera"

Comment: Maybe then they are implying a 1 based indexing for the Array rather than a 0 based indexing?

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not an error. [Project Euler says](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25):

> Hence the first 12 terms will be:
>
> F<sub>1</sub> = 1
>   F<sub>2</sub> = 1
>   F<sub>3</sub> = 2
>   ...
>   F<sub>11</sub> = 89
>   F<sub>12</sub> = 144

Note the little subscript numbers bottom right of each "F". **Those are the indexes.** So they start indexing with 1, and thus "position" and "index" are equivalent here. In particular, we can see that the first Fibonacci number with three digits is at index 12.

Your choice of programming language and data type and that language's choice of indexing doesn't override what's in the problem statement. And if it did, there'd be a problem because there *are* programming languages that start indexing with 1.

In the comments below you talk about "common terms" and what they "usually mean". I'm sure you realized that Project Euler is very mathematical, and in mathematics, those subscripts are the indexes. See for example [Index notation in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation#Index_notation_in_mathematics). Btw, **all** the examples there start indexing with 1 (not 0), because that's a common/usual way in mathematics as well.

Comment: Excuse me, how is it my fault that they chose to use a word that is a common programming term for a purpose other than what it usually means in coding terms?

Comment: Their choice is not your fault. Also, check out the paragraph I just added.

Comment: If you didn't regard it as my fault, you wouldn't have said the error was mine.  There is clearly a phrasing issue in this problem.

Comment: I said their choice is not your fault. You *did* err in your interpretation of their question. Please look up "error" and "err" in a dictionary if you disagree. You asked about an error, and I just said it's you who erred.

Comment: I didn't err, I got steered wrong. I followed their instructions to the letter.  They're the ones that gave me the wrong letter.  Why, for the love of crispy tacos, would you use the word "INDEX" to mean anything other than the index of an array in a  coding prompt?  Surely a word other than index or a short sentence to the effect of "The nth Fibonacci number is the first to have 1000 digits; find n" would have been clearer?

Comment: Like I just added to the answer, **that's what it means in mathematics**. It's not like that's some uncommon fringe thing Project Euler made up.

Comment: They still should have specified.  Last time I checked these problems are all  coding prompts. I would expect most of the overlapping terminology to defer to coding.

Comment: @AaronGodhard this is not a complete list but I think it gets the point across https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)

Comment: @engineersmnky Well, *one* of the points :-). But yeah... in the big table I counted 19 programming languages starting indexing at 1.

Comment: @AaronGodhard I rewrote the summary statement at the beginning now since you seemed somewhat upset about that, hope it's better now.